# Change result group text before replacing?

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace each `'\w(space)\w'` to `'\w\w'` (without spaces).

```
Pattern.compile("\\w \\w").matcher("a b c d e f ...").replaceAll("$0")
```

May I change result in '$0' group (remove spaces) before replacing?

I need to return 'ab cd ef'

**More complex example:**

`123 321 321 ... 123 number` -> `123321321...123 number`

by regular expression `(\d{3} )+(number)`

Comment: What are rules of removing or leaving space?

Comment: Only spaces between block of numbers are removed.

Comment: That doesn't match with your previous requirement where `"a b c d e f"` should become `"ab cd ef"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this simple case each match would have a single space, so removing the space would mean replacing with an empty string. Moreover, `String` can do it directly, like this:

```
String res = "a b c d e f ...".replaceAll("\\w \\w", "");
```

A more interesting case is when you need to process each match as you do replacements. In this case you should use [`appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) and [`appendTail`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail(java.lang.StringBuffer)) methods, which work in tandem:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w \\w");
Matcher m = p.matcher("a b c d e f ...");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "#");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform some operation on the matched result, then you have to use an extra `StringBuffer` for that, and `Matcher.appendReplacement()` method.

You can however achieve this without that too:

```
String result = "a b c d e f".replaceAll("(\\w) (\\w)", "$1$2");
```

Comment: Your snippet return 'abcdef' but I need 'ab cd ef'

Comment: It works, but if i need transform each '123 231 ... 123 number' to 123231...123 number'. I don't know count of groups of three numbers. Expression: `(\d{3} )+number`